# Parent div obstructs focus of its child

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make a simple plugin to be able to make a div draggable. Of course a div can have a content inside (typically a form) and it should be dragged with it.

Here is a prototype: http://jsfiddle.net/Xcb8d/539/

The problem is that the texbox inside this div never gets focus, so I cannot type in it:

```
<div id="draggable-element">Drag me!
<form>
    <input type="text" style="width:50px;"/>
    <button>ok</button><br><br>
    <input type="checkbox">check it</input>
 </form>
</div>
```

As you can see, this does not happen to other elements on the form. Checkbox can be regularily used, as well as the button.

In addition, I would like only the grey coloured area to be draggable, and not the inner elements. On this example, you can place the mouse cursor fully inside the textbox and start the drag of the whole parent div.

Comment: You don't need closing tag for input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the onmousedown handler on the draggable element return false and there by stopping event propagation, allowing it will make the input focus-able and the dragging still works. (at least on chromium)

```
document.getElementById('draggable-element').onmousedown = function (e) {
    // memorize the offset to keep is constant during drag!
    x_offset = e.clientX - x_elem;
    y_offset = e.clientY - y_elem;    
    _drag_init(this);
    return true;
};
```

Comment: Typing work nice, but there is a strange secondary effect now. When I drag the element around, parts of the screens are changing colour. A scrrenshot: http://snag.gy/GRm3m.jpg This happens easier, as you drag the element faster. Any ideas how to get rid of this?

Comment: returning false; in _move_elem seems to help, as it prevents the default event action of selecting.

Answer (score 1):

In your `onmousedown` handler you end with a `return false`. This prevents the click event from happening when you click on the input, and thus it never gets focus. What I think you are looking for is this:

```
// Bind the functions...
document.getElementById('draggable-element').onmousedown = function (e) {
    if (e.id == 'draggable-element') {
        // memorize the offset to keep is constant during drag!
        x_offset = e.clientX - x_elem;
        y_offset = e.clientY - y_elem;    
        _drag_init(this);
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

paradoxix's answer was correct in stating that the `return false`on the `mousedown` event is preventing the propagation of all other events.

On any element listening to the `mousedown` event you won't have any problems, because the event happens for them first, and only after for the box itself. But the input listens to the `focus`event, which never happens due to the `return false` in the box's event.

The solution is to prevent `onmousedown` from bubbling from the child elements into the box, like so:

```
var nodes = document.getElementById('draggable-element').childNodes;
for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].onmousedown = function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xcb8d/546/

Comment: Copy-paste mistake, apologies. You prevent bubbling of events with stopPropagation(), but the wrong code got copied in the end. Updated.

Comment: Also, the current selected answer does not prevent the final requirement of your question, and is therefore not complete. It does answer your initial question, but if that is enough, please update your question to prevent confusion.